# How to exclude transitive depdency of one depedency in maven-dependency-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I have one project that has one dependency which has already shaded its transitive dependencies. So I'd like to exclude this dependency's transitive dependencies, but keep other dependencies' transitive dependencies. How can I do it in maven-dependency-plugin ? Thanks

Comment: If you have already a shaded artifact which is packaged to contain the other transitive deps you can't use maven-dependency-plugin to remove them...which will not work cause it's more than just extracting...Furthermore why do you need maven-dependency-plugin?

Comment: I just want to copy its dependencies to somewhere, and later I will run the program via one script which will build the java command and also its classpath.

Comment: There plugins which can generate the scripts see https://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/ and a combination of this plus maven-assembly-plugin can do this...no manual copying via maven-dependency-plugin needed.